# Scroll page not div CSS only

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I have been struggling with this problem for a long time now, and although I have found a number of good solutions to parts of my problem, none of them seem to work combined, so I have decided to ask you.

Here is a scrn shot of the website:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C0k1.jpg

What I'm hoping to achieve is to have a scroll bar appear on the far right of the page when content overflows the blue container, the div that has all my content in it, not the far right of the div itself, like it would if I set the div to *overflow: auto* or *overflow: scroll*.

In other words, I would like the page to scroll, not my div.

The site essentially consist of a body background, a div for the menu and a div for the content. The code is pretty messy, so I have left it out, but if you need it, just leave a comment and I will add it right away.

Everything is supposed to be fixed as in remain like it is on the scrn shot, except for the content in the blue container to the right. I initially figured that setting everything except the container to *position:fixed* would work and trigger a scroll bar to appear for the page that could be used to scroll through the div, but it didn't. This doesn't work though, as any visible overflow in the container just 'leaves' the page; it doesn't trigger a scroll bar.

As I've also pointed out in the scrn shot, the container-div has padding on the top and bottom and is also slightly transparent.

These two features seem to make things even more difficult. The padding, because setting *overflow: visual* makes content overflow, and thereby be visible, even through padding.
The transparency is an issue, since I can't just *cut out* the padding and give it a z-index that's higher than the content itself, in order to hide it; it will still be visible through it. The background image is set at a percentage or set to 'cover' (still figuring out which one works best), so cutting out the padding with the segment of the background image it covers, will not work either.

I hope I presented my problem and the issues clearly enough. If you have any questions or any feedback, please leave a comment.

Thank you in advance for any replies, 
Magnus

**NOTE:** This is a repost of an early question that was trashed by someone who didn't bother reading through it properly before rating it down. The question essentially died  afterwards. I have tried to make things even more clear this time, so I'm sorry if I repeat myself. This is also the reason why my post is so long this time.

Comment: you can try positioning your div as fixed.

Comment: That just leaves the additional content overflowing without tiggering a scroll bar.

Comment: "This doesn't work though, as any visible overflow in the container just 'leaves' the page; it doesn't trigger a scroll bar." <= From this, im guessing you are using "Height" on the container div, Use "min-height" to allow the div to grow if required. Also, The padding at the top and bottom will have to be done on the body.

Comment: Sounds like you might be onto it, I'll try it out.

Comment: if you want the div to triggered a scroll you have to change the  height dimension of your div

Comment: Sorry, still no scroll. Even when overflow is set to auto/Scroll for the body and the div's position isn't defined.

Comment: @Nudier You mean I need content to overflow the div? I added that, sorry I left that out in the post and the scrn shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/6R7c2/

HTML:

```
<div id="top">Top</div>
<div id="middle">
    <div>Content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#top,#bottom{
    height:10%;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
}
#middle{
    height:80%;
    overflow:auto;
}

#middle>div{
    height:10000px;
    border:25px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Possibly. I think you might have left out the problematic areas though, but I will fiddle with it to see if that's the case. :) Just a sec.

Comment: I can't really figure out how to add the menu to your fiddle in a way that works.. How id you make the "middle" div scroll, not the "ontent" div that actually contains the overflowing stuff?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund If *problematic areas* mean the menu, see http://jsfiddle.net/6R7c2/11/. The content div has a height of 10000px, which is more than `#middle`'s height. Then, it appears a scrolling bar and the content div is scrolled.

Comment: There was the answer! I need to define the height in pixels to a level that will exceed any resolution in order for it to trigger the page scroll-bar. I tried this early on with height 100%, but I guess that's 100% of the initial viewpoint, not the content? Anyway, thank you for your help! It solved my problem :)

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund I don't understand very much your last comment, but if I solved your problem feel free to mark my answer as the accepted answer. If you set `height:100%` to an element, its height will be the same as his parent's element; or if it has `position:absolute`, its first ancestor with `position` different than `static`; or if it has `position:fixed`, the window.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not thinking straight at all right now. I think you helped me out enough that I can get the rest solved on my own, BUT is there a way to make the scroll-bar fill out the enitre height? Not just the "middle" div? Like, cover the "bottom" and "top"?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund Not natively, but you could fake it, for example, overlapping elements. But you shouldn't do that because each browser can have scrollbars of different widths.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this

see http://jsfiddle.net/QfsvB/

**CSS**

```
div.scroll 
{
background-color:#00FFFF;
width:100px;
height:100px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout, the overflow property specifies what to do if the content of an element exceeds the size of the element's box.</div>
```

Comment: The div being the blue container I have, right? In that case, won't this just trigger a scroll bar on the right side of the div, as opposed to the page?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund this will trigger a scrollbar to the container div.

Comment: Exactly. I'd like a scroll bar on the body/page instead. One that does the same as what you have up there though. :)